# How to add a constant value in a column in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to create the following:
I have a column in Excel named "names"

```
Names
-----
Mary White
Bob Smith
```

and I want this column to become as follows:

```
Names
-----
Mary45 White45
Bob45 Smith45
```

Does anyone know a way to achieve this in Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Select the cell, and type in what the value should be? Seriously though it's not clear what you're asking. Why is "Mary White" Mary45 White45? Is it just the first name and last name plus "45"?

Comment: I want to have the FirstName+45 and the LastName+45..
The names are more than 17.000 so I cannot do it manually

Comment: I supposed you could use a 2nd column, and set the formula in column B to something like `=left(A2,find(A2," ") & "45" & right(A2,find(...))&"45".  Replace "45" as needed.  Alternately, you're getting into VBA and doing the same thing by looping through the table and replacing the first space with "45 ", etc.

Comment: Or -  `=CONCATENATE(LEFT( A1, FIND( " ", A1 ) - 1 ) & "45", " ", RIGHT( A1, LEN( A1 ) - FIND( " ", A1 ) ) & "45")`. Copy this down all the rows, select the values, "Paste Special (Values)" onto the first column, and delete the temporary column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it in two times: add "45" at the end of the cell value, and replace every occurrence of a space by a "45 ":

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1&"45";" ";"45 ")
```

Comment: Hello,I tried this and I get the following output: Mary 45White45

Comment: I want to get Mary45 White45

Comment: ... or =REPLACE(A2,FIND(" ",A2),1,"45 ")&"45".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this.

```
sub addColt1911acp()
    dim i as long, arr as variant

    with worksheets(1)
        arr = .range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(.rows.count, 1).end(xlup)).value2
        for i = lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)
            arr(i,1) = trim(join(split(arr(i, 1) & chr(32), chr(32)), "45 "))        
        next i
        .cells(2, 1).resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)) = arr
    end with

end sub
```